# android- adding new activity in android settings menu

Tags: android

i want to add one of my app activity in android phone settings where it has other settings like Application, Call Settings,  Display, Sounds, Date & Time etc etc..
 for ex-click on MENU->Settings->CardSettings.
how do i add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you have any permission to do so. I think this quit impossible to add in native phone.

You can create settings via Settings helper class that look the same as system settings, but they will be part of your app, not part of system settings menus.

Answer (score 2):

you can't add tour activity in phone's settings. you can register your application for what you want (ringtone provider, sms sender/receiver, etc).

Answer (score 2):

No that's quite not possible the way you want it unless you go ahead and build your own OS by customizing android source itself.

You can still setup your activity and try working with

> android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS

or similar. Basically it should invoke intent chooser giving your activity as an option but as far as putting in something new is concern customizing OS is the only option... its like you are asking to put your application activity in someone else's application... it wont work that way man :)