# Reg: intentfilter settings activity android

Tags: android, mobile

Can anyone help me how to restrict uninstalling of application such as "netnanny" android app?   https://play.google.com/store/search?q=netnanny&c=apps

[android- adding new activity in android settings menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119652/android-adding-new-activity-in-android-settings-menu)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported means of blocking the uninstallation of an app. The various hacks for doing this have been reported as security issues, as malware authors would be keenly interested in preventing apps from being uninstalled.